# Telnet works but email doesn't

Tags: email, amazon-ec2, server, alfresco, telnet

I'm setting up an Alfresco AWS instance and trying to configure inbound email.

As per [the documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/email-inboundsmtp-props.html) I've configured it, hosted the Alfresco mail server on port 1025, set up an iptable rule to forward port 25 --> 1025, set up an folder in Alfresco with the alias 'dropoff' and added my work email as an allowed user for sending emails. I've also ensured all the ports are open on the EC2 instance

So far so good. If I test everything from my local computer with `telnet`:

```
helo mywork.com
mail from:myname@mywork.com
rcpt to:dropoff@alfresco.mywork.com
data
From: adinihan@mywork.com
Subject: test mail from command line

this is test number 1
sent from linux box
.
```

Then it works. I look in the Alfresco folder and there's the test email document. However, if I use Gmail and sign into `myname@mywork.com` and send an email through Gmail, then it doesn't work. It sends alright and there's nothing in Alfresco logging, however the document just never appears in the Alfresco folder. The from/to address is the same as the telnet command's one.

Since I can telnet from my local computer to the instance I assume it's not an issue with ports on the EC2 instance. Why would telnet work but sending it via Gmail not?

EDIT: got an email back from Google about an hour after I sent it with the error message `TLS Negotiation failed: generic::failed_precondition: starttls error (0): protocol error`

EDIT 2: here are my inbound emai settings in the global properties file

```
# Inbound #
email.inbound.unknownUser=anonymous
email.inbound.enabled=true
email.server.enabled=true
email.server.hideTLS=false 
email.server.enableTLS=true 
email.server.requireTLS=false
email.server.port=1025
email.server.domain=alfresco.amritmro.com

imap.server.enabled=true
imap.server.port=1143
imap.server.host=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: What about an MX record in DNS?

Comment: Good point, I had one before but I just checked and it's since been erased. Would the record name be the same as the actual value, i.e. the 'mail server' would also be `alfresco.mywork.com` since that's the domain where Alfresco is hosted and Alfresco is acting as the mail server?

Comment: Yes.  Theoretically, when a host accepts mail for its own hostname an MX record is optional, according to RFC-5321, but I would suggest that you have one, and while you're checking records, ensure that the A record is intact.  Also, it does need to be a A-Record and not a CNAME.

Comment: I added the MX record and verified the A record. Still not working, however I just got an email from Google saying the email failed, with the error  `TLS Negotiation failed: generic::failed_precondition: starttls error (0): protocol error`  so at least that's another lead

Comment: Aha.  Does "Alfresco" support TLS?  Does your (corporate?) Gmail account require it?  https://support.google.com/a/answer/2520500?hl=en

Comment: Can you share your inbound mail config settings which can be found in alfresco-global.properties?

Comment: Ok added to the post at the bottom